# How do I create a simple "news feed" inside my Angular App?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web

Im working on a static Homepage right now. 
Im a beginner in Web-Dev and also a beginner in using Angular.

**What I want:**
I want my site to take Data outside of a spreadsheet (or any other data source) and display it on my Page, so I don't have to rebuild my page each time the Data changes. 
The Data should be 1 single sentence. Not more.

I does not matter if its a spreadsheet or another online services, it just should be easy to implement.

**What i have tried:**
I have tried making this work with google spreadsheets. But to be honest, I don't know enough to do it by myself and the tutorials I tried didn't work or i didn't understand

**Example:**
I open google spreadsheet (or whatever is the best option here).
I write "Im on vacation until 12.03" inside the sheet.
My Site takes the Data / Sentence and display it somewhere, so someone visiting my site knows im on vacation

Im looking for the simplest method to implement those functionality. I dont need JSON format or anything. Just 1 sentence that i write /change from time to time to display on my Website without the need to rebuild the angular app.

Greetings

Comment: You could probably use something like pastebin or github gists to store the actual data, then use their public API to fetch the contents when rendering the page.

Comment: Please share your code!

Comment: @KamilNaja There is no code for the question im asking here. I dont know how or where to start for my question, so there is no code to share :(

Comment: @CollinD Im pretty sure this is possible, it will work the same way as google spreadsheet i guess. But still i dont know how to do it :( The tutorials i find online archive something else or are not for angular

Comment: https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/beginner-apis/

Comment: Also this is from the sheet to your app: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading